# TensorFlow Setup for Udacity Deep Learning

Tags: linux, github, virtual-machine, tensorflow

I am trying to setup TensorFlow for Udacity Deep Learning (https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730). I read the instruction (https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6452084188/m-6560586345) but am need more direction

I want to:
1) Understand how to get setup to Run the Docker container from the Google Cloud repository.
2) Install TensorFlow on your computer (Linux or Mac OS X only), then fetch assignment code separately. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/README.md does not tell me this.

This is so I can run and learn independent of Google too. I am not sure which VM or Linux (CentOS) to use, special VM memory set up etc.

I appreciate your assistance. thanks!

Comment: are you on linux ? do you know docker?

Comment: Hi  fabrizioM: I have a windows 7 system and was contemplating:1) setting up a CemtOS VM, thinking of virtual toolbox but its been awhile and then 2) learning about google cloud and docker, I am clueless, did AWS. 3) creating a full stand-alone TensotFlow configuration on CentOS. I need detailed advice. the math I know everything else I am a bit weak on as its been awhile. Thanks! I will start along a pat of least resistance :-) Chris

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@Rapchik/running-google-s-deep-learning-course-material-under-windows-82d468b6d5be#.8acsjam1c

Everything I wanted ... it works!